# What is the grey/blue rectangle in Playground called?

Tags: xcode, swift-playground, xcode9-beta

In Xcode 9 Beta, there is a grey/blue rectangle in Playground to print result just below the print command rather than printing the result in Console.

What do we call this control?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's "App Development with Swift" calls it the **Show Results** button.

> “To view more details inline, you can use the Show Results button.
>   ”

Excerpt From: Apple Education. “App Development with Swift.” Apple Inc. - Education, 2017. iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/app-development-with-swift/id1219117996?mt=11